# How to redirect all mail from one domain to another in Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, redirection

I have two forms of the same domain name, one being a common misspelling of the other, let's say tedswidgets.com and tedswigets.com.

I'd like to redirect all mail for <someone>@tedswigets.com to that same <someone>@tedswidgets.com.

There's plenty of information on how to catch all mail from a domain and redirect it to a single address, but I don't want to do that - I want to catch all mail from a domain and redirect it, keeping the username part, and remap it to the equivalent address on the other domain.

*Sorry, I should have mentioned that I use virtual alias domains and have a lot of other domains that I serve email for on this server. These two domains are the only two of many that need to mirror each other.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add tedswigets.com to your virtual_alias_domains list and then in your virtual file add:

```
@tedswigets.com       @tedswidgets.com
```

According to [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) when the result has the form *@otherdomain* the result becomes the same user in *otherdomain*.  So @tedswigets will catch all anyuser@tedwigets.com emails and the @tedswidgets in the result will cause it become anyuser@tedswidgets.com.

Comment: It's not presently necessary to do anything with `virtual_alias_domains`, just the part in the `virtual` file is sufficient.

Comment: The virtual file *is* the virtual_alias_domains list.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this another domain to postifx `mydestination` list. See  http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#local