# Email aliases redirect from example1 to example2 domain

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, email, postfix

I  need to achieve following functionality:

User send email to example@example1.com that now is not existing email. I buy this domain (example1.com) and would like auto redirect all emails that incoming into example@example1.com to example@example2.com which belongs for other company. Domain example1.com will be used only for this email alias.

I have VPS server with Ubuntu, nginx installed, for example, with ip 80.70.60.50.

How I can configure that functionality? What type of dns records I should select?

Answer (score 0):

Two options actually:

---

- When you have control over the `example2.com` mail server(s):
  in most mail server software you can add an alias domain such that for any existing `mailbox@example2.com` mailbox the corresponding email address `mailbox@example.1.com` will also get accepted and delivered  there.

You will need to look up existing MX  DNS records for `example.2.com` for instance with `dig MX  example.2.com` and set the same one(s) for the `example.1.com` domain. That would result in something like

```
example1.com.      IN MX 5  smtp.example2.com.
example1.com.      IN MX 10 relay.example2.com.
```

And then configure those existing mail server  (`[smtp | relay].example2.com.`)  to accept mail for the new alias domain.

---

- When you don't have control over the `example2.com` mail server(s):
  You will need to run on your VPS your own SMTP server (for instance postfix, exim, sendmail) that will accept mail for @example1.com and for each email address forward the message to the corresponding email address @example2.com.

You will need to create DNS MX records to deliver incoming email for @example1.com to your VPS:

```
example1.com.      IN MX 5  smtp.example1.com.
smtp.example1.com. IN A     <ip-address of your VPS>
```

And then set up for instance with postfix: [How to redirect all mail from one domain to another in Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/q/266855/37681)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in DNS control panel i cannot attach MX record to domain, there are only ip address field accepted.